# CollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath doesn't work - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` but it doesn't work.

```
    collection_contactus.allowsSelection = true
    collection_options.allowsSelection = true

    collection_options!.dataSource = self
    collection_options!.delegate = self

    collection_contactus!.dataSource = self
    collection_contactus!.delegate = self

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       print("test")
//        if(collectionView == collection_options)
//        {
//
//        }else{
//            print("test: \(indexPath)")
//        }
    }
```

I can't see any output.

Comment: Using the correct method signature will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Swift 3.2. That method was renamed to [`collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) in Swift 3.0:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: FYI - It was renamed in Swift 3.0, not 3.2.